# Kodaira Dimension of a Calabi-Eckmann manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

What is the Kodaira dimension of a Calabi-Eckmann manifold, $X$, when the underlying topological manifold is $S^{2p+1} \times S^{2q+1}$ where $p \geq 1$, $q \geq 1$ and $p \neq q$ ?

Comment: A Calabi-Eckmann manifold is a principal bundle under an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{CP}^p\times \mathbb{CP}^q$. It follows easily that its Kodaira dimension is $-\infty$.